# Regex for getting just name of street and number from messy address

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have this list of messy addresses, some are clean some aren't:

```
Av. Chorrillos # 1759 Local 1082 Exterior Jumbo
Av. Balmaceda N° 2355 Local BS - 121 / Subterráneo sector servicios
Tarapaca N° 729
```

The structure is usually `name of street` + `N°|#|nothing` + `number` + `extra stuff`

I'd like to erase this extra stuff so that the expected output from the above list is:

```
Av. Chorrillos # 1759 
Av. Balmaceda N° 2355
Tarapaca N° 729
```

I tried using a combination of letters and lookback:

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+\d+)
```

But the `#` and `N°` gave me trouble, so I tried also including them

```
([(\w|°|#)\s]+\d+)
```

but still no luck.

I know regex on addresses is a nightmare, but any regex that fits those three cases above would fit 95% of my list, which is good enough for me!

I'm using this with `python` `regex` in case that matters.

You can find the list of addresses and my regex attempt on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0fmyM8/2)

(Some addresses have extra info BEFORE the relevant information of `street + number`, but I'm fine with screwing up those)

Comment: _I'm using this with python regex in case that matters._ That's why we have tags.

Comment: @rahul I think a python tag would be an overkill. In fact, it didn't matter for the solution :). Also, whoever made a downvote, please explain why it's too broad, otherwise it's hard to correct. I'm giving an expected outcome for a very particular regex for addresses, not asking for a general solution for addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your specifications. I came up with this regex.

**Regex:** `^.*?(?:[N°#Nº]\s*)?\d+`

**Explanation:**

- `^.*?` consumes everything from beginning of string. Since match is lazy it will match until next part which is `(?:[N°#Nº]\s*)?`
- `(?:[N°#Nº]\s*)?` matches optional `N°#Nº` followed by zero or more whitespaces.
- `\d+` matches numbers.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifpa1k/1/)**